# Can't get FitVids to work, getting "$(...).fitVids is not a function" error

Tags: jquery, reactjs, responsive

I have a react app I made using create-react-app. I have some videos on the site and I'm working to make the app responsive. I found the FitVids library (https://github.com/davatron5000/FitVids.js/) which is supposed to do exactly that but I haven't been able to get it to work. I think I'm botching something basic with jQuery.

I'm including script tags in my index.html file to include jQuery and link the FitVids file to my app. I've tried putting the script tags in  and in , and I've put the folder containing the jquery.fitvids.js file in the root folder, the public folder and the src folder (appropriately updating the path in the script tag as I go) and nothing seems to work, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

In my index.html file:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/jquery.fitvids.js"></script>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    // Target your .container, .wrapper, .post, etc.
    $(".video-container").fitVids();
  });
</script>
```

In the console I keep getting the error: "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).fitVids is not a function".

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: why are you combining react and jquery?

Comment: My understanding was that the FitVids library needed jQuery to function.

Comment: ther is something wrong in the process if incuding Fitvids lib.. make sure you have the current file and it is loading properly.